# How do I construct an ECFieldElement object with the F2m constructors?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, elliptic-curve, spongycastle

```
    X9ECParameters params = SECNamedCurves.getByName("secp256k1");
    ECDomainParameters CURVE = new ECDomainParameters(params.getCurve(), params.getG(), params.getN(), params.getH());
    ECCurve.Fp curve = (ECCurve.Fp) CURVE.getCurve();
    ECFieldElement x1 = new ECFieldElement.Fp(curve.getQ(), x);
```

How do I get the same ECFieldElement object as above, but with the constraint that I can only use any of the following constructors.

```
    public F2m(int m, int k1, int k2, int k3, java.math.BigInteger x);

    public F2m(int m, int k, java.math.BigInteger x);

    private F2m(int m, int k1, int k2, int k3, org.spongycastle.math.ec.IntArray x);
```

I'm no crypto expert. I  don't know what all these other parameters are.

Answer (score 1):

Fp is a finite field whose elements are numbers from 0 to p-1.

F2m is a finite field whose elements are binary strings of length m bits, which means numbers from 0 to 2<sup>m</sup>-1.

secp256k1 is a curve over Fp field. It can be represented as `org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint.Fp` (or equivalent spongycastle class) whose purpose is to contain the definition of Fp curve.

It can not be represented as `org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint.F2m` (or equivalent spongycastle class) whose purpose is to contain the definition of F2m curve.

If you do not know what is Fp, or F2m, or secp256k1 or what do `ECPoint.F2m` constructor parameters mean you should stop immediately. Hacking your way around cryptography without understanding what are you doing until it *seems to work* will lead to disaster sooner or later.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if just DJ Bernstein should practice EC crypto, but that does not make the last statement less true...